# Generating next alphabetical sequence from given alphabet in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

I have to generate Ids in alphabetical order.

Suppose Existing Id is - **A**
So I have to check the max existing letter and then generate next.
**Like next will - B** and so on.
So I have generated from A to Z.

**But after "Z" again need to generate AA,AB etc like wise.**

I have tried using below query-

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(CHR(ASCII(TRIM (REGEXP_SUBSTR ('Z_2203','[^_]+')))+1),'[A-Za-z]') FROM DUAL;
```

sample data from comment :

Present_id

```
    A_2004 
    B_2004
    C_2004
    '
    '
    '
    Z_2004
```

Expected Result-

```
 B 
 C
 D
 '
 '
 '
 AA
 AB
```

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. (All as formatted text, not images.)

Comment: Sample Table:-  
Input data 
`Present_id
A_2004
B_2004
.
Z_2004`

`Expected Result-
B
C
.
AA`

Comment: Present_id A_2004 B_2004 . Z_2004 Expected Result- B C . AA  individually is it??

Comment: After "Z" it should give AA , then AB,AC like this.

Comment: for Z you have to generate AA after that??? i mean after Z what will come??

Comment: Stop this before it's too late and use a numeric sequence!

Comment: @nikhil sugandh :yes exactly.After Z,AA will come .After AA ,AB will come.

Comment: when Z it replaces AA but when to place AB??

Comment: When table will contain AA ,then next id should be AB....same sequence like AB,AC,AD.....etc

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like this recursive function:

```
create or replace function alpha_id(i_id in varchar2) return varchar2 is
begin
  if trim(translate(i_id, 'Z', ' ')) is null then 
    return rpad('A', nvl(length(i_id), 0) + 1, 'A');
  end if;

  if substr(i_id, length(i_id), 1) = 'Z' then 
    return alpha_id(substr(i_id, 1, length(i_id) - 1))||'A';
  else
    return substr(i_id, 1, length(i_id) - 1) 
        || chr(ascii(substr(i_id, length(i_id), 1)) + 1);
  end if;
end alpha_id;
```

Noting special here, just manipulations on strings and recursive call if last char is `Z`. Test:

```
with t(rn, id) as (
    select 1, 'A'   from dual union all
    select 2, 'N'   from dual union all
    select 3, 'Z'   from dual union all
    select 4, 'AA'  from dual union all
    select 5, 'BP'  from dual union all
    select 6, 'QZ'  from dual union all
    select 7, 'ZZ'  from dual union all
    select 8, 'BPZ' from dual union all
    select 9, 'ZZZ' from dual )
select rn, id, alpha_id(id) next_id from t;
```

Result:

```
    RN ID  NEXT_ID
 ----- --- ---------
     1 A   B
     2 N   O
     3 Z   AA
     4 AA  AB
     5 BP  BQ
     6 QZ  RA
     7 ZZ  AAA
     8 BPZ BQA
     9 ZZZ AAAA
```

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
SELECT * FROM D061_WORDS;
A_2004
B_2004
Z_2004

select case when ascii(chr(ascii(substr(a,1,1))+1))<=ascii('Z') then
chr(ascii(substr(a,1,1))+1) when ascii(chr(ascii(substr(a,1,1))+1))>=ascii('Z') then
'A'||chr(ascii(chr(ascii(substr(a,1,1))+1))-26) end from D061_WORDS;

B
C
AA
```